# Is Joda-time 2.1 backward compatible with 1.6?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a legacy component that uses Joda-time-1.6. I am integrating something new to complement this legacy component and the new component requires Joda-time 2.1.

So, can I use Joda-time 2.1 lib with the legacy component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found below block in the Joda documentation pointed to by Fatehi.

---

Compatibility
 The change in major version indicates compatibility issues.
 Please read the detailed notes below.
 If your code just *used* Joda-Time and had no deprecation warnings then you
 will *probably* see no issues.

---

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/upgradeto200.html

Answer (score 2):

Try a Google search before posting the question? 
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/upgradeto200.html